# Determining order class of $T(n) = n\cdot T(\frac{n}{2}) + 1$ with $T(1) = 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> Solve the following equation of
>   recurrence, specifying the upper asymptotic limit:
>
> $\left\{\begin{matrix}
> T(1) = 1
> \\ 
> T(n) = n\cdot T(\frac{n}{2}) + 1
> \end{matrix}\right.$

I'm trying the iterated method:

$T(\frac{n}{2}) = \frac{n}{2} \cdot T(\frac{n}{2^2}) + 1 \\
T(\frac{n}{2^2}) = \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot T(\frac{n}{2^3}) + 1 \\
T(\frac{n}{2^3}) = \frac{n}{2^3} \cdot T(\frac{n}{2^4}) + 1 \\
...$

$\Rightarrow$

$T(n) = n \cdot \{ \frac{n}{2} \cdot [ \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot ( \frac{n}{2^3} \cdot T(\frac{n}{2^4})+1)+1] +1\}+1 \\
...\\
= \frac{n^4}{2^6}\cdot T(\frac{n}{2^4})+\frac{n^3}{2^3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+n+1$

And then I'm stuck.
I don't see any repetitive pattern.
What I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have reference on your definition of "order class"?  I cannot find corresponding definition online, sorry about that.

Comment: I have to determine the Big-O

Comment: Is $n$ necessarily an integer? If so, how is $T(n/2)$ defined? If not, how do you recursively define $T(3)$, for instance, if you don't know $T(3/2)$ or $T(3/4)$ or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=2^k$, then
\begin{align}
T(2^k) = 2^k\cdot T(2^{k-1}) + 1&\implies T(2^k) = 2^k\cdot 2^{k-1}\cdot T(2^{k-2}) + 2^k + 1\\
&\implies T(2^k) = 2^{k(k+1)/2}\cdot T(2^{k-k}) + \mathcal{O}(2^{k(k+1)/2})\\
&\implies T(2^k) = 2^{k(k+1)/2}+ \mathcal{O}(2^{k(k+1)/2})\\
&\implies T(n) =\mathcal{O}(n^{(\log_2n+1)/2})\\
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand how you find that $T(2^k) = 2^{k(k+1)/2} \cdot T(2^{k-k})+O(2^{k(k+1)/2})$

Comment: @gekoramybean Iteration $k$ times

Comment: $T(2^k) = 2^k \cdot [ 2^{k-1} \cdot T(2^{k-2})+ 1 ] +1$

$= 2^{2k-1} \cdot T(2^{k-2})+2^k+1$

$= 2^{2k-1} \cdot [ 2^{k-2} \cdot T(2^{k-3}) + 1 ] + 2^k + 1$

$= 2^{3k-3} \cdot T(2^{k-3}) + 2^{2k-1} + 2^k + 1$

$= ...$


How can you see that the 1st $2^{x}$ has $x = k(k+1)/2$?

Comment: @gekoramybean $1+2+...+k=k(k+1)/2$

Comment: I'm looking to the exponent of the 1st $2$, because I think that your $2^{k(k+1)/2}$ comes out iterating it, right?

If so I don't see $1+2+...+k$
I see $k \rightarrow 2k-1 \rightarrow 3k-3 \rightarrow ...$

Comment: @gekoramybean Well, it's just $k\to k+(k-1)\to k+(k-1)+(k-2)$, thus we have $k+(k-1)+...+2+1$ in the end.

Comment: Now I see it!
And in the last pass you simply change $2^k$ with $n$.
Ans so $\frac{(k+1)}{2} = \frac{\log_2(n) + 1}{2}$, right?

Comment: @gekoramybean Yeah, exactly.

Comment: But what if you find $T(2^k) = x + O(y)$ with $x \neq y$? What would be the final $O$ in that case?

Comment: @gekoramybean The bigger one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72632/discussion-between-gekoramy-bean-and-aforest).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can show $T(n)=1/2+\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{n^i}{2^{i!}}$ by induction.

I don't know if you can find a closed-form expression for this, but you can bound it (for example) by $T(n)\leq 1/2+\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{n^i}{i!^2}\leq\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{n^i}{i!}=e^n$

Answer (score 0):

The most significant "repetitive pattern" I see in

$$ \fbox{ $\frac{n^4}{2^6}\cdot T(\frac{n}{2^4})$ }+ \fbox{$\frac{n^3}{2^3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+n+1$}$$

is that the second box seems asymptotically insignificant in comparison to the first box. This suggests the following path to solving the problem:

- Find an asymptotic description of that first term
- Prove that $T$ actually satisfies the claimed description

Another way to formulate this path is to first find the asymptotic behavior of the recurrence

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
S(1) = 1
\\ 
S(n) = n\cdot S(\frac{n}{2})
\end{matrix}\right.$$

and then prove that $S$ and $T$ both have the same asymptotic behavior.

Comment: I find that $S(n) = c \cdot n^{\log_2n} \cdot S(1) \Rightarrow O(n^{\log_2n})$
How can I demonstrate that $S$ and $T$ have the same asymptotic behavior?